# What is the URL when I DELETE an object

Tags: json, django, api, rest, backend

I'm running a local server playing around with an API using Django. I have a model called 'Users' populated with a few objects, and am using DefaultRouter.

I want to know what the URL would be if I were to DELETE a specific object from this model. For example, if I wanted to GET a user with an ID of 1 in this model, the URL would be: "localhost:8000/Users/1/". What would the equivalent be to DELETE this user?

I found an explanation of this on the REST API website (below), however, I don't understand what any of the syntaxes means.
[image: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/]

What is {prefix}, {url_path}, {lookup} and [.format]? If anyone could provide an example of what this might be using a localhost that would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us take an example of an API (URL) to update book data with id (pk) being 10. It would look something like this:

```
URL: http://www.example.com/api/v1/book/10/

Method: PUT/PATCH
```

With some data associated.

If you want to delete you just need to change method to `DELETE` instead of put or patch.

Regarding your second question lets compare the url with the parameters.

prefix: http://www.example.com/api/v1/book

lookup: 10

format: It specifies what type of data do you expect when you hit the API. Generally it is considered to be json.

url_path: In general, every thing after look up except query string is considered to be url_path.